# Python 3.4 Openpyxl error

Tags: python, import, module, openpyxl

I'm having a problem with Python when importing module openpyxl. I'm using Python 3.4 and have followed instructions and managed to install the module. 
When I'm importing the module like this:

```
from openpyxl import workbook
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from openpyxl import workbook
ImportError: No module named 'openpyxl'
```

I installed the module following this step-by-step method:

1. I went in to the control panel - system and security - System - advanced system - system - enviroment variables - find path in the scroll bar and write in at the end where Python is installed. After this is done you can go in CMD and write python and it will find it.
2. In your modulepackage you downloaded there is a setup.py look up the directory of this. 
   Go to the CMD  and write in cd followed by the directory.
3. Then write python setup.py and the setup will begin.
4. After the setup is done go in to the CMD and write python and then import "module name" if no error is shown the setup is finished.

**Help me Stackoverflow, you're my only hope!**

Comment: How did you install the module?

Comment: Can you list the steps you used in the question? That way, the question will be self-contained, in case that video is ever taken down. You can [edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25973363/edit) to add the information

Comment: I don't know where you got those instructions from but I'm sorry to say they're not very good. openpyxl should either be installed using pip or from a checkout as it says in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you, i will try installing it using pip then.